# LinkedIn Marketing API for posting comments and reactions

Tags: node.js, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I have been trying to request access to LinkedIn Marketing API to mainly use it for posting comments and reactions directly from our application.

There is this particular question "What is your intended use case? (select all that apply)".

I'm not sure if this is the right question for us to answer because we won't be using the APIs for "Campaign Management" or "Reporting & ROI".

Can someone clarify what should be responded to this question?
Or is there any other way to implement the intended operation?

Tried looking for the documentation but couldn't find any proper documentation explaining how to use the APIs without requesting APIs

Comment: _"to mainly use it for posting comments and reactions directly from our application"_ - not sure what _that_ would have to do with advertising?

Comment: You need to apply for Community Management API for posting comments.

Comment: Hey @CBroe, thank you for replying. The document says we need certain access to be able to post comments/reactions which are available in the API access only. Also, sorry its LinkedIn Marketing API Program

Comment: Hey @BrahmaDev, thanks for replying. Its under Marketing API only

Comment: What document exactly are you referring to? And what exactly do you want to post comments and reactions _on_ - the ads themselves?

Comment: Hey @CBroe, I want to post comments/reactions on other people's posts using APIs.
Here is the document link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/quick-start?view=li-lms-2024-03#step-1-apply-for-api-access

Comment: _"couldn't find any proper documentation explaining how to use the APIs without requesting APIs"_ - if they wanted you to be able to do that, they would probably not have set up this process to apply, in the first place.

Comment: _"I'm not sure if this is the right question for us to answer"_ - of course they want an answer to that question from you, otherwise they would not be asking. _"because we won't be using the APIs for 'Campaign Management' or 'Reporting & ROI'."_ - if these are the only two valid use cases they are giving, and what you want to do doesn't fit either of them - then they likely won't let you use it.

Comment: _"I want to post comments/reactions on other people's posts using APIs"_ - and what makes you think, the _Marketing_ API was the correct one for this task? Comments API, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/community-management/shares/comments-api, is part of the Community Management API.

Comment: Hey @CBroe, please check the link that you shared. It is under the Marketing APIs only.
And the button for selecting Community Management API is disabled with this message "This product cannot be requested because there are currently other provisioned products or other pending product requests."

Comment: Doesn't change that you need to apply for the Community Management API. And if you can't currently do that, because you already have a request pending, you will probably have to wait, until that is resolved.

Comment: Hey @BrahmaDev, can you provide any way to apply for Community Management API without requesting for Advertisement APIs? On Products page, the button is disabled

Comment: Hey @CBroe, there is no other request pending from our side. The Community Management API button is disabled on the screenshot shared in the official documentation also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/media/apply-program.png?view=li-lms-2024-03

Comment: Hey @BrahmaDev, yes as I mentioned in the above comments also, it says "This product cannot be requested because there are currently other provisioned products or other pending product requests.". But there is no pending requests from our side.

Comment: @RipanChoudhary Which means you have provisioned products. You need to create a new app, and apply for Community Management API for that.

Comment: Hey @BrahmaDev, thanks for the help. Figured it out

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.